# Insert data to phpMyAdmin mySQL database from Shell Script

Tags: raspbian, gpio, database

I would like to seek help on inserting data whenever the switch is on or off to my phpMyAdmin mySQL database from my Shell Script. I'm using Raspberry PI as my hardware and I have follow this [**LINK**](http://www.instructables.com/id/Web-Control-of-Raspberry-Pi-GPIO/?ALLSTEPS) to create my own Web Control Interface. I have created a mySQL database and insert into my phpMyAdmin. After I implemented insert method to my GPIOServer.sh and execute it, my shell script can't work at all, my LED never light up and never store into mySQL database.

This is my GPIOServer.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysqlusername="USERNAME HERE"
mysqlpassword="PASSWORD HERE"

#Set  Refresh
echo "How long do you want the wait time to be?"
read waitTime

#Invoke GPIO
echo "4" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "17" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "18" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "21" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "22" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "23" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "24" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "25" > /sys/class/gpio/export

#Start Loop
while :
do
#Read MySQL Data
#Direction
direction4=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinDirection FROM pinDirection WHERE pinNumber='4'";)
direction17=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinDirection FROM pinDirection WHERE pinNumber='17'";)
direction18=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinDirection FROM pinDirection WHERE pinNumber='18'";)
direction21=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinDirection FROM pinDirection WHERE pinNumber='21'";)
direction22=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinDirection FROM pinDirection WHERE pinNumber='22'";)
direction23=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinDirection FROM pinDirection WHERE pinNumber='23'";)
direction24=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinDirection FROM pinDirection WHERE pinNumber='24'";)
direction25=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinDirection FROM pinDirection WHERE pinNumber='25'";)
#Status
status4=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinStatus FROM pinStatus WHERE pinNumber='4'";)
status17=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinStatus FROM pinStatus WHERE pinNumber='17'";)
status18=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinStatus FROM pinStatus WHERE pinNumber='18'";)
status21=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinStatus FROM pinStatus WHERE pinNumber='21'";)
status22=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinStatus FROM pinStatus WHERE pinNumber='22'";)
status23=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinStatus FROM pinStatus WHERE pinNumber='23'";)
status24=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinStatus FROM pinStatus WHERE pinNumber='24'";)
status25=$(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword gpio -e "SELECT pinStatus FROM pinStatus WHERE pinNumber='25'";)

#Run Commands
if [ "$direction4" == "out" ]; then
    echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/direction
    if [ "$status4" == "1" ]; then
        echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value
        $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("1","Red LED", dateTime,"")";)
        echo "GPIO 4 Turned On"
    else
        echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/value
        $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("1","Red LED", "", dateTime)";)
        echo "GPIO 4 Turned Off"
    fi
else
    echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio4/direction
fi
if [ "$direction17" == "out" ]; then
        echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction
    if [ "$status17" == "1" ]; then
                echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value
                $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("2","Blue LED", dateTime,"")";)
                echo "GPIO 17 Turned On"
        else
                echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value
                $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("2","Blue LED", "", dateTime)";)
                echo "GPIO 17 Turned Off"
        fi
else
        echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction
fi
if [ "$direction18" == "out" ]; then
        echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction
    if [ "$status18" == "1" ]; then
                echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
                $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("3","Green LED", dateTime,"")";)
                echo "GPIO 18 Turned On"
        else
                echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
                $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("3","Green LED", "", dateTime)";)
                echo "GPIO 18 Turned Off"
        fi
else
        echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction
fi
if [ "$direction21" == "out" ]; then
        echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio21/direction
    if [ "$status21" == "1" ]; then
                echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio21/value
                $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("4","Yellow LED", dateTime,"")";)
                echo "GPIO 21 Turned On"
        else
                echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio21/value
                $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("4","Yellow LED", "", dateTime)";)
                echo "GPIO 21 Turned Off"
        fi
else
        echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio21/direction
fi
if [ "$direction22" == "out" ]; then
        echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio22/direction
    if [ "$status22" == "1" ]; then
                echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio22/value
                $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("5","LED", "","")";)
                echo "GPIO 22 Turned On"
        else
                echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio22/value
                $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("5","LED", "", "")";)
                echo "GPIO 22 Turned Off"
        fi
else
        echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio22/direction
fi
if [ "$direction23" == "out" ]; then
        echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/direction
    if [ "$status23" == "1" ]; then
                echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value
                $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("6","LED", "","")";)
                echo "GPIO 23 Turned On"
        else
                echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value
                $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("6","LED", "", "")";)
                echo "GPIO 23 Turned Off"
        fi
else
        echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/direction
fi
if [ "$direction24" == "out" ]; then
        echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio24/direction
    if [ "$status24" == "1" ]; then
                echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio24/value
                $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("7","LED", "","")";)
                echo "GPIO 24 Turned On"
        else
                echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio24/value
                $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("7","LED", "", "")";)
                echo "GPIO 24 Turned Off"
        fi
else
        echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio24/direction
fi
if [ "$direction25" == "out" ]; then
        echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio25/direction
    if [ "$status25" == "1" ]; then
                echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio25/value
                $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("8","LED", "","")";)
                echo "GPIO 25 Turned On"
        else
                echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio25/value
                $(mysql -B --disable-column-names --user=$mysqlusername --password=$mysqlpassword sensor -e "INSERT INTO sensor values("8","LED", "", "")";)
                echo "GPIO 25 Turned Off"
        fi
else
        echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio25/direction
fi
#Complete Loop
sleep $waitTime
done
```

This is my sensor mySQL database in phpMyAdmin:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sensor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sensor` text NOT NULL,
  `switchOnLog` datetime NOT NULL,
  `switchOffLog` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This is the error I got when executing GPIOServer.sh:
[image]

This is the result I should be getting from sensor mySQL database if it success:
[image]

Comment: put `#!/bin/sh` on the first line, also make it executable: `chmod +x GPIOServer.sh`

Comment: jet, I got an error

Comment: I'm sorry, but who wrote this shell script? Is it yours? Anyway, the errors are all related to the status-variables. What are the values of those? Please add debug prints and share the results.

Comment: I follow the tutorial and edit a bit, it works when I never implement WRITE method to mySQL database, Bex. I just added a screenshot result of sensor mySQL database what will be shown if it success, Bex.